# Regular Expression Tweak Needed

Tags: regex

I would appreciate some quick help on a regular expression in Perl. I'm hoping a regex expert can quickly spot what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to match strings of the following form and reject anything else:

```
1.2
1.2_EB4
1.2_FB4
1.2.3
1.2.3_EB4
1.2.3_FB4
```

The "1", "2", "3", and "4" can be any non-negative integers, but the "EB", "FB", underscore, and dots are fixed.

Here is what I have so far. (Don't worry about hours/minutes/seconds, and FYI yes, I am dropping the "1" and reordering the "2", "3", and "4".)

```
my $hours = 0;
my $minutes = 0;
my $seconds = 0;

#                          [ws]  123   .   456  [ .  789  ]  [ _xB      234 ]
#                          --- ------ -- ------  -- ------    ------- ------
my ($found) = ($input =~ /^\s*([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]+))?(\_[EF]B([0-9]+))?/);

if ($found)
{
    $hours = $2;
    $minutes = $6;
    $seconds = $4 if ($4);

    $hours   = 0 if ($hours   eq "");
    $minutes = 0 if ($minutes eq "");
    $seconds = 0 if ($seconds eq "");
}
```

Here is what I'm getting for certain inputs:

```
+---------+--------+-------+
|  Input  |Expected| Actual|
|---------|--------|-------|
|1        |  false | false |
|1.       |  false | false |
|1.2      |  2:0:0 | 2:0:0 |
|1.2.     |  false | 2:0:0 |
|1.2.3    |  2:0:3 | 2:0:3 |
|1.2_     |  false | 2:0:0 |
|1.2_E    |  false | 2:0:0 |
|1.2_FB   |  false | 2:0:0 |
|1.2_EB4  |  2:4:0 | 2:4:0 |
|1.2_GB4  |  false | 2:0:0 |
|1.2.3_   |  false | 2:0:3 |
|1.2.3_E  |  false | 2:0:3 |
|1.2.3_FB4|  2:4:3 | 2:4:3 |
|1.2.3_GB4|  false | 2:0:3 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks.

Comment: One big thing that will help your readability is to use `\d` (for digit) instead of `[0-9]`, so that `[0-9]+` is just `\d+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick a `$` on the end of the regex, and it should work:

```
/^\s*([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]+))?(_[EF]B([0-9]+))?$/
```

<sub>You can find an online explanation and demonstration [here](https://regex101.com/r/lM3bD7/1)</sub>

Without the `$` anchor, the regex will match the `1.2` part of `1.2.`, `1.2_`, `1.2_E`, `1.2_FB`, `1.2_GB4`, `1.2.3_`, `1.2.3_E`, and `1.2.3_GB4` and then quit without trying to match more.

If you don't need to capture the numbers in capturing groups, you can simplify it a bit:

```
^\s*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){1,2}(?:_[EF]B[0-9]+)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/lM3bD7/2

Answer (score 1):

You could use anchors and simplify your regex a bit.

```
/^\d+(\.\d+){1,2}(_[EF]B\d+)?$/
```

Comment: I tried to copy/paste this in, but it doesn't appear to work as-is. I'm getting 0:0:0 for the 1.2 and 1.2.3. inputs, and some of the others aren't looking good either.

Comment: @jia103 does perl support `\d`

Comment: @AmitJoki I think jia103 needs the separate capturing groups.

Comment: Not sure. I'm not a Perl expert, but I do understand there are differences among various flavors of regular expressions depending on the environment (e.g. Visual Studio, TextPad, sed, perl). In case it matters, this is the ccperl that comes with IBM ClearCase.

Comment: @jia103 I am not either :) But as The Guy with The Elf Hat said, it might be grouping problem.